# How do i signal EOF to a NodeJS file in windows command line?

Tags: node.js, terminal

I've tried Ctrl+D, Ctrl+Z, Ctrl+Z+Enter, for EOF in commandline, VSCode terminal, and Gitbash on windows and none works.
Ctrl+C will exit the nodejs file alltogether.
I've spent the whole morning googling about this but unfortunately, I haven't found an answer. It seems that for most people Ctrl+Z+Enter has been the solution, but not for me!

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: What do you mean with "signal EOF"? Do you want to exit the node process or just send a signal? And what is "EOF", End Of File?

Comment: hey thanks for responding,
End of File yes.
I don't want to exit node I can do that by Ctrl+C
instead I want to tell my code that the input has ended and it can now return the result of code.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)